# How to login to app using qr-code scanning?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to android development and want to use an already printed QR-code to authenticate users(same QR-CODE all the time).Users register by providing their legal name, SSN, and phone number then after authentication succeeds a welcome screen with user's name is displayed how do I do it?
I'm aware of the security concerns this method might have but this is a personal project that wont be a real life app.
And I use firebase to save users data.

Answer (score 0):

Have the serve generate a random UUID and encode that in the QR code.  When you scan the QR code, you get the UUID and send that to the server's login endpoint.  The server looks in its QR code table, finds the account its registered to, and logs them in as that account.  Then it should delete that code form the DB-  this should be a one time use code.  That's fairly secure, so long as you delete it from the db and aren't worried about someone else snapping a picture first (physical security exists).

Comment: Will the QR-code be a one time use too? Sorry for not providing all the information but I want to use an already printed QR-code to auth all users(same QR-CODE all the time).

Comment: That wouldn't really be possible.  If you use the same QR code, how would you tell which user is which?  You'd need them to enter in a username as well, in which case your QR code is just a universal password, which is a really bad idea.  The idea behind using a QR code is a unique QR per account.  Reusing the same code would really only work for a demo-like scenario (like giving access to a single account at a trade show)